# "'/bin/sh' is not a Traefik command: assuming shell execution." in WSL2

Tags: docker, wsl2

```
version: "3.3"

services:

  traefik:
    image: bluelake/traefik-dev:1.0.0.1
    container_name: "traefik"
    command:
      - /bin/sh
      - -c
      - sh /configuration/download.sh  && sh ./entrypoint.sh traefik
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: './docker/traefik/Dockerfile'

    restart: always
    
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "81:81"
      - "443:443"

    volumes:
      - ./configuration:/configuration
      - ./traefik.yml:/etc/traefik/traefik.yml
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro

    networks: 
      - webgateway

networks:
  webgateway:
    external: true
```

This is my docker-compose file

and when I run docker-compose up I get:

```
traefik    | = '/bin/sh' is not a Traefik command: assuming shell execution.
: not found| /configuration/download.sh: line 2:
```

I changed the download.sh file to an empty file and I was still getting the same error after I ran:

docker-compose --build in order to rebuild the whole traefik image, but I still got the same error. Do you know why? The only thing that made it work was removing:

```
sh /configuration/download.sh
```

I am wondering what I need to do to get bin/sh working on my WSL2 instance. There seems to be a problem with bash and WSL2 for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used Traefik, but this just looks like a problem in the compose file.

You'd need to provide your dockerfile to be sure, but it sounds like there's an `entrypoint` (a *Docker* entrypoint, not a Traefik entrypoint) specified there (or in the base container) that makes `traefik` the default command that runs when the container starts.  As a result, the docker-compose `command` is being passed as an argument to `traefik`.

You can see an example of this in the [Traefik doc](https://doc.traefik.io/traefik/v1.7/#1-launch-traefik-tell-it-to-listen-to-docker) where the compose file that they give shows:

```
command: --api --docker
```

As you can see, these are arguments, not commands.  And they are (likely) being passed to the traefik command.

I'm not sure exactly what you are trying to accomplish, but to run those scripts when the container starts, you'll likely need to override the entrypoint in the compose file.